# Embed mapbox in Joomla module

Tags: joomla-3.x

Does anyone have an idea how to embed Mapbox map into a joomla module?
(To create and use Mapbox map it requires free account sign up).

This is an example simple map https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/.

Answer (score 1):

From the linked example, it looks like you need to include a script and stylesheet in the head area of the HTML page and a script into the body area.

The best practice for inserting code into the head area is to use a third party extension such as [EasyScript](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easyscript) or similar. Your template may also have an option allow you to add custom code into the head area. You could also edit the `index.html` file of your template but this is not considered good practice as future template updates would likely overwrite your customisations.

The body code can be inserted into an article or Custom HTML module or similar but you may need to use another third party extension such as [Regular Labs Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer) or similar so that the editor does not strip out the `<script>` lines when you save your content.